# Can we preserve cookies in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I wanted to know is there any way by which i can preserve cookies in cypress.
I tried automating a feature in cypress for my application and i'm unable to load the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
    whitelist: ["cookie_name", "cookie_name" ]
    });
```

// test describe function

```
    afterEach(() => {
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce();
    });
```